# I am not able to sending mail by using code below even after successfully completion of my batch class

Tags: apex, email, batch, notification

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'my mail id'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('some mail id');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Lavanya');
mail.setSubject('Batch Process Completed');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Batch Process has completed');

}
```

Comment: I added that but still it's not working. Is any permissions needed in My org to send Email.

Answer (score 2):

There is missing:

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Unless it is just mistake pasting code this is the issue

Comment: I added this line, but it's showing an error  COMPILE ERROR: Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage
LINE: 9 COLUMN: 58

Comment: My bad, i've pasted line for mass email... Now it should be ok :)

Comment: @Lavanya if this answer is the corect one, please mark it as accepted (click the checkmark below the arrows and number)